Doxygen java how to hide package names in class list
Can I change this Class List to start with the last three packages by hiding com, token and signer packages? This way it is hard to reach the classes.
From:
├── Class List
│   └── com
│       └── token
│           └── signer
│               ├── client
│               ├── entities
│               └── exceptions

To:
├── Class List
│   ├── client
│   ├── entities
│   └── exceptions

I tried using HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES to YES. Also added some INPUT_FILTER but it did not work for class list.
Class list

Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you add a small example?

My doxygen version is 1.11.0. I added my class list as image. I want it to be not show common package name like com. It is little challenging to reach classes this way.

Example please so we can try to reproduce the problem (i.e. a smal java file and the used settings in the form of doxygen -x Doxyfile)

Have you tried STRIP_FROM_PATH and FULL_PATH_NAMES? That is working for file path. Not sure if it works for Class List "paths"
